# RecylerView Pagination

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, pagination

I have a wallpaper app and im getting image data from api and problem is im getting all images from api thats why it takes too much to load so i want to add pagination for better optimization but the thing is i don't want to use mysql cause i have so much images. How can i add pagination without mysql?

Json
[
{
"url": "http://.com/Wallpapers/Animals/790669.jpg",
"time": "2021-04-21 08:41:17"
},
{
"url": "http://.com/Wallpapers/Animals/790810.jpg",
"time": "2021-04-21 08:41:17"
}
]

My Code

```
private void getData() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, dataurl+name, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("files");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject imgObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    WPList imgList = new WPList();
                    imgList.setURL(imgObject.getString("url").toString());
                    imgList.setDate(imgObject.getString("time").toString());
                    anlist.add(imgList);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity2.this, 3));
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            adapter = new WallpaperAdapter(MainActivity2.this, anlist);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "No Available Image Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("tag", "onErrorResponse: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    // Add JsonObjectRequest to the RequestQueue
    jsonObjectRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    queue.getCache().clear();
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);


}
```

Comment: when do you request images? In `onBindViewHolder` of Adapter?

Comment: @anatoli Yes onBindViewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Requests:

- to get list of all wallpapers
- to read an image

So you can solve a problem without pagination:

- load new images first, when user scrolls to some item.

  - make request in `onBindViewHolder`, if image was not downloaded already.
  - store already requested images in app internal storage. So by scroll up you will not need to load data again.

How to:

- in Activity/Fragment make the method to request an image

  - make a count of requests (if user scrolls to see 3 items - count = 3). First when all done, make `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`
- provide Activity/Fragment-instance as Interface to Adapter.Holder
- set for each item some `minHeight` to load only small count of items at same time.
- in `onBindViewHolder` check if file with image already exists.

  - if url = "..Wallpapers/Animals/790669.jpg", so create File with same name, first create a folders also, in local storage.
  - if file exists - just read and show an image
  - if not exists - make request

Comment: I'm already caching images with glide. The problem is when first loading, it takes too long because loading every image on that category and so slow, also im already loading new images first.

Comment: Glide.with(context).load(anlist.get(position).getURL()).thumbnail(0.30f).apply(new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).override(200, 200)).into(holder.imageView);

Comment: `onBindViewHolder` is called only on items, that are visible. If you already makes requests in `onBindViewHolder`, first you have said in `onCreate`, then problem of long loading would be not solved with pagination. It sounds like low internet speed or some other problem. Show a loading view while download files.

Comment: If you makes 200 requests on begin, i have described, how to reduce it to small count. If that is not a case, please describe your problem better from begin.